# login page enter correct username and password

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

The login page displays an error message indicating failure to login, even when the correct username and password combination is entered. What is the cause of this problem?

```
try {
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mydsn","sa","password@123");
String sql = "select customer_id, fname, lname, email_id, phone_number from customer_details where user_name=? and password=?";
PreparedStatement stmt;
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
session.setAttribute("customerId", rs.getString(1));
session.setAttribute("userName", userName);
session.setAttribute("fName", rs.getString(2));
session.setAttribute("lName", rs.getString(3));
session.setAttribute("emailId", rs.getString(4));
session.setAttribute("phoneNumber", rs.getString(5));
conn.close();
%>
<jsp:forward page="welcome.jsp" />
<%} else {%>
Sorry! You have entered an invalid username or password. Please try again.
<%}
conn.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: With this code it's impossible that you got an error page with "Sorry! You have entered an invalid username or password. Please try again". It would have thrown a HTTP 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 5):

it is because

```
PreparedStatement stmt;
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

`stmt` is `null`

**Few suggestions for your code:**

- [Avoid java code in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- write java code in [`servlet`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- Handle exceptions properly